# MYSQL - DATE/TIME show last 30minutes

Tags: mysql, string, date, select

I have a column (lastlogin) that contains the following `value = '17th May 2017 09:40:43 AM'` ----

php function to create stamp:

```
date('jS F Y h:i:s A');
```

How can I do a select query that shows the (lastlogin) in that last 30 minutes from current time?

I'm guessing we have to convert date/time to string and separate the 2?

Any help would be amazing.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following but did not work returned more aless of records in table:

```
  SELECT user_id, ('lastlogin' >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'%D %M %Y %H:%m:%s %p')) as result
  FROM login_last
  where lastlogin >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE,'%D %M %Y %H:%m:%s %p')
  GROUP BY user_id
```

**TABLE Structure**

```
   [id] int(8)  
   [user_id]    int(11)
   [lastlogin]  varchar(30) 
   [browser]    varchar(300)
```

Comment: To do a comparison, you'll need to either compare as datetime types or formatted datetimes that will "sort" properly. Is it stored as a string or datetime/timestamp?

Comment: stored as a string

Comment: Can you show your table schema (__Edit your question with the info__)? To provide an answer, I need to know the table name and the column names involved.

Comment: I've updated my question with these  details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert your string date to a datetime format for the comparison, then compare the current datetime to the value stored.

You could also convert them to sortable strings for comparison. Something like *"2017-05-17 10:20:10 AM"*, but it's easier to compare using the datetime type.

**Reference:**

- [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

**MySQL Query:**

```
SELECT 
    `user_id`,
    `last_login`,
    (STR_TO_DATE(`lastlogin`,'%D %b %Y %h:%i:%s %p') >= (NOW() - (INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))) as `in_range`
FROM `login_last`
WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`lastlogin`,'%D %b %Y %h:%i:%s %p') >= (NOW() - (INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)))
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? If you are going to down-vote, at least provide a reason so the person can improve their answers going forward.

Comment: THIS WORKED..THANK YOU! had to change last_login to lastlogin...you get an up vote from me thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked, you're welcome! I also updated the answer with the correct column name

Comment: @SloanThrasher I think someone downvoted all answers here :P. I didn't know about STR_TO_DATE so I will happily leave a +1 for you :).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE lastlogin >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

The challenge is to convert the result of `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)` to the correct format `'17th May 2017 09:40:43 AM'` (or format the left condition alias your lastLogin to UNIX_TIMESTAMP / datetime). In case you are inserting the date values yourself you probably already know how to get that format and can complete that yourself. Otherwise I recommend you to create a new question which is about formatting UNIX_TIMESTAMPs to your desired format.

A blind guess without having the chance to try that on my on would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastlogin) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Comment: Using that format won't compare correctly since it's a string and that format  won't compare correctly.